# failed connecting mongodb in jboss

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc, jboss

while deploying a war file which connects to mongodb to jboss, I got the following error:

```
Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "moc-public-api-1.0_SNAPSHOT.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {
        "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./public-api/v1" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./public-api/v1: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/core/ResourceMethod
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod from [Module \"deployment.moc-public-api-1.0_SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
        "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
            "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"moc-public-api-1.0_SNAPSHOT.war\".deploymentCompleteService"],
            "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mongoDriver"]
        }
    },
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

My datasouorce in the standalone.xml is like this:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/mongoDS" pool-name="mongoDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/test</connection-url>
    <driver>mongoDriver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name></user-name>
        <password></password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

And my driver in the standalone.xml is like this:

```
<driver name="mongoDriver" module="com.mongodb">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mongodb.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

The error shows `"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mongoDriver"]`, is my mongodb jdbc driver configuration correct?

Comment: Have you tried with latest driver?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your deployment `moc-public-api-1.0_SNAPSHOT.war`. Your deployment needs resteasy classes but they're not within the class loader scope.

You can add the dependencies either by [adding entries to the manifest file](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-MANIFEST.MFfile) or by creating [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-jbossdeploymentstructure.xml) and shipping it together with your deployment.

**Example jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```